# How do i draw an square with an alpha square in the center

Tags: actionscript-3

I know how to draw a square:

```
graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00, 1);
graphics.lineTo(point, 0);
graphics.lineTo(point, point);
graphics.lineTo(0, point);
graphics.lineTo(0, 0);
graphics.endFill();
```

now how would i draw another square inside the first one with an alpha of 0.5?

Comment: Don't you know about drawRect?

Comment: Sure - but i figured this would come closer to what i wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having to use any blend modes, you can **exclude** portions of a drawn shape by drawing over (erasing) the desired portion before ending the fill.

Here's an example:

```
import flash.display.Shape;

var squares:Shape = new Shape();
squares.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
squares.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
squares.graphics.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100); //exclude
squares.graphics.endFill();
squares.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 0.5);
squares.graphics.drawRect(75, 75, 100, 100);
squares.graphics.endFill();

addChild(squares);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The following snippet will draw a green square then substract a square to its center ([live demo](http://wonderfl.net/c/v5o3)).

```
// Size of the main square
var point:uint = 100;

// Create two sprites
var s1:Sprite = new Sprite();
var s2:Sprite = new Sprite();

// Shortcuts to graphics objects
var g1:Graphics = s1.graphics;
var g2:Graphics = s2.graphics;

// Draw the main square
g1.beginFill(0x00ff00, 1.0);
g1.drawRect(0, 0, point, point);
g1.endFill();

// Draw the eraser square 
g2.beginFill(0x000000, 0.5);
g2.drawRect(0, 0, point/2, point/2);
g2.endFill();

// Configure blend modes to erase the center of the first square
s1.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
s2.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;

// Add the eraser square to the first one and adjust its position
s1.addChild(s2);
s2.x = s2.y = point/4;

// Add the first square to the stage
addChild(s1);
```

Comment: Thx - problem is i need the center-square to erase/overwrite the main square.

Answer (score 2):

```
var squ1:Sprite = new Sprite();
with(squ1.graphics){
    beginFill(0xFF0000);
    drawRect(0,0,100,100);
    endFill();
}
addChild(squ1);
var inSq:Sprite = new Sprite();
with(inSq.graphics){
    beginFill(0x00FF00,.5);
    drawRect(0,0,25,25);
    endFill();
}
squ1.addChild(inSq);
inSq.x = squ1.width/2 - inSq.width/2;
inSq.y = squ1.height/2 - inSq.height/2;
```

Comment: Thx - i need the second one to cancel out the first one though. Not just overlay.

Comment: I didn't get you. What you want to do?

Comment: Its hard to explain ;-) - but see florents live demo: http://wonderfl.net/c/v5o3 - it does exactly what i want.